# Preload exception handler to have assambly available (started from shared folder)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, network-share

Our C# .NET application is able to be started from a network share. But if the connection to the network or at least to the mapped drive breaks we are not able to log the occurrence nor to handle the exception (show friendly message) because the necessary code is in a not loaded assembly I guess.

The result is always the windows dialog that tells the program is not responding and after that the program crashes.

Is there an approach to pre-cache all the necessary assemblies (code) to have id available in case of network outage?

Comment: Assemblies are not loaded in full, either. They are mapped as a DLL and paged in. If the network goes down you could see random access violations/inpage faults I think.

Comment: You could do a "fake" exception at the beginning of the program just to log it, to force the execution at least once of all the code you need.